# Python how to make json from string and call api?

Tags: python, json, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a list of data that looks like below-

```
product-0
product-1
product-10
product-100
product-1000
product-10000
product-100000
```

But data can exceed more than 100.

And I want to make api call to facebook graph api. Call looks like below-

```
fb_graph_url = api_endpoint+product_catalog_id+"/products?fields=image_url,retailer_id,id&filter={'or':[{'retailer_id':{'eq':'product-0'}},{'retailer_id':{'eq':'product-1'}}]}&access_token="+access_token
```

AS you can see in the api call `product-0` and `product-1` are the data from the above list.

In order to get all data in a single call I am using filter in the api call.

I want to make json that looks like `[{'retailer_id':{'eq':'product-0'}},{'retailer_id':{'eq':'product-1'}}]`.
Right now it contain only two products. I want to call this api with all the above list data.

Please help.

Comment: have try to find in documentation different operators instead of `eq` - like `'starts_with':'product-1'` or `'contains':'product-1'` - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-set

Comment: BTW: to create this string with all elements you would need only `for-loop`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the help of below function-

```
def call_fb_api(ids):
api_endpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/"
filter_param = "filter={'retailer_id':{'is_any':[" + ','.join("'{0}'".format(w.strip()) for w in ids) + "]}}"
fields_param = "fields=image_url,retailer_id"
limit_param = "limit=1000"
token_param = "access_token=" + access_token
fb_graph_url = api_endpoint + product_catalog_id + "/products?" + limit_param + "&" + fields_param + "&" + filter_param + "&" + token_param
response = requests.get(fb_graph_url).json()
return response['data']
```

Thanks everyone for your help.